# AngularJS manipulate image with canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, image

What would be a good library to have a look at?

My requierments are:

- Ability to load image including drag and drop (can be handled with ng-file-upload) so sorted.
- Place an image inside the canvas.
- Draw on the image with (Free Pen, Circle, Square)
- Features: Line thickness, Color, Line style, ...
- Add Text To the image
- Text Features: Bold, italic, Color
- Save the result to a new image including the "background image" loaded at the beginning.

Is there already a library or open source project that can cover all this?

I found a-lot of stuff how to do each function seperatly but I would think that many have a similar requests so I hope there is a library already for something like that that is fairly easy to integrate into AngularJS?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here. software / library / tool recommendation are usually off-topic here.

Comment: I believe this library does what you have in mind http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing